# iFrame on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I am trying to create a toolbar on top of my website to be used on an iphone. However, iframe is giving me considerable trouble in that it refuses to allow the page to scroll. Here's my code:

```
<iframe id="myIFrame" src="http://www.bloomberg.com" 
    runat="server" frameborder="0" style="position: fixed; top: 65px; left: 0px; width: 100%; overflow:auto;"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onresize = setHeight;

    function setHeight() {
        var myScreenHeight = screenHeight();
        var theIFrame = document.getElementById("myIFrame");
        theIFrame.height = myScreenHeight - document.getElementById("toolbar").clientHeight + "px";

        return false;
    }

    function screenHeight() {
        var myHeight = 0;
        if (typeof (window.innerWidth) == 'number') {
            myHeight = window.innerHeight;
        } else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
            myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        }
        return myHeight;
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(setHeight);
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can scroll iframes in Mobile Safari by using two fingers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to have native scrolling, and fixed position toolbars in webkit on iphone.

This javascript plugin tackles that exact issue by replicating the scrolling and allowing fixed position toolbars: http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

Comment: this seems a bit over the top for a silly toolbar. is there a simpler way to do the toolbar in general?

Comment: Not if you want it to stay there while you scroll. This is the simplest way - I have rally looked into this. If you were making a native app, you could create a web view the size of the scrolling area, and it would work how you want, but as a website, not possible.

Comment: What if i don't want it to stay there while I scroll?